# Concurrent HTTP requests with limit in pool and with exceptions

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2016

I have been looking for the perfect library that does async requests in batched pools. I have looked at `p-limit`, `tiny-async-pool` and others but they all have the same limitation for what I am trying to do, namely `Promise.all` fails if any request fails.

What I have found in several projects, is that sometimes doing many requests to servers, they respond with a 500, normally this is because is a proxy server, having this failure is expected and can be safely retried. So I would like to capture a given error, throw it with a custom error, I can then pick up on the async pool function, and use `Promise.allSettled` to collect the errors and run them recursively.

So I have gone into `tiny-async-pool` [source code](https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool/blob/master/lib/es7.js) and modified it so it does just that,

This is what I have done:

```js
const data = [
  'https://apple.com',
  'https://ibm.com',
  'https://microsoft.com',
  'https://amazon.com',
  'https://apple.com',
  'https://sony.com',
  'https://hp.com',
  'https://dell.com',
  'https://compaq.com',
  'https://apple.com'
]

// Concurrency Limit
const poolLimit = 3
// Final array
const processedData = []

// Mock API response promise
const API = (item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (item === 'https://apple.com') reject(`${item}/repeat`)
    setTimeout(
      () => resolve(item.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '')),
      Math.round(Math.random() * 2000) + 4000
    )
  })
}

// Iterator Function - It throws the error asyncPool will pickup as timeout exception
const fetchAPI = async (item) => {
  try {
    processedData.push(await API(item))
  } catch (error) {
    throw { name: 'timeout', error }
  }
}

// Async pool. 'Recursive' modification of tiny-async-pool
async function asyncPool(poolLimit, array, iteratorFn, exception) {
  const promises = []
  const queue = []

  for (const [index, item] of array.entries()) {
    console.log(`\rProcessing ${index + 1}/${array.length} ...`)

    // Iterator is always a promise from the API
    const pro = iteratorFn(item, array)
    promises.push(pro)

    // If concurrent limit exceeded
    if (poolLimit <= array.length) {
      // Is it removing the promise after resolving it?
      const racer = pro
        .then(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(racer), 1))
        // If I do not catch I get uncaught exeption
        .catch(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(racer), 1))

      queue.push(racer)

      if (queue.length >= poolLimit) await Promise.race(queue)
    }
  }

  // Collect promises results
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

  // Make array with exception errors
  const rejected = results
    .filter(({ status, reason }) => status === 'rejected' && reason.name === exception)
    .map(({ reason }) => reason.error)

  // If we have any errors run recursively
  if (rejected.length) {
    await asyncPool(poolLimit, rejected, iteratorFn, exception)
  }
}

// Start pool request
;(async () => {
  await asyncPool(poolLimit, data, fetchAPI, 'timeout')
  console.log(processedData)
})()
```

I am fascinated by what `tiny-async-pool` does, but there is this part that even thou I know what is doing I cannot explain how:

```
const racer = pro.then(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(racer), 1))
```

And so because I am throwing an error on a condition, I need to add a `catch` before the `Promise.race()` runs.

```js
const racer = pro
  .then(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(racer), 1))
  .catch(() => queue.splice(queue.indexOf(racer), 1))
```

it works, but again I cannot really explain why.

Could anyone shed some light on this?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: The `exception` is a string argument called 'timeout' , I send it to the `asyncPool` function, when it is thrown from the `fetchAPI` the `asyncPool` runs recursively. The asyncPool receives it as `reason.name` when the `Promise.allSettled` gets the results